# I want to delete a Selected Item in List view and it should delete the same item in the tree view

Tags: vb.net

[enter image description here][1]Good evening. I love to program in my free time, wished I did it as a career, but I'm only a beginner. Stack flow has really helped me out with a program that I am working on but I can't seem to get this code right.

I am using VB.net and I have a list view box where I added command buttons to: Add, Remove a selected item and clear the list view box.

The problem I'm facing, is that when I Select maybe: "Item 3" to Delete in the List box, it deletes perfectly when I click the "Remove Item" in the "List view", but it will not remove the "Same Item 3" in the "Tree view" and at the same time.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

The Code is as follows: This is only for the List View. I don't have a code for the treeview

```
Private Sub RemoveItems_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click, btnRemove2.Click, btnRemove3.Click, btnRemove4.Click, btnRemove5.Click, btnRemove6.Click,
        btnRemove7.Click

    'Remove items from the Non-Current Asset listview box

    If sender Is btnRemove Then
        If IsNothing(lvwNonCurrent.FocusedItem) Or lvwNonCurrent.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("First select the item from the list you would like to remove", "Warning Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        ElseIf lvwNonCurrent.Items.Count = 1 Then
            For Each r As ListViewItem In lvwNonCurrent.SelectedItems
                lvwNonCurrent.Items.Remove(r)
                btnRemove.Enabled = False
                btnClear.Enabled = False
            Next
        Else
            'Remove item from TREEVIEW


            For Each i As ListViewItem In lvwNonCurrent.SelectedItems
                lvwNonCurrent.Items.Remove(i)

            Next


        End If
    End If
```

Comment: What is *it* in *but it will not remove the same "Item 3"*? Did you define a relation between the ListViewItems of your ListView and the Nodes of your TreeView? That's something you have to do, there's no implicit / automatic relation between these collections (neither the ListView or the TreeView have a DataSource that can be set, so there's no BindingSource in between). You'll have to write the logic yourself.

Comment: Firstly, you need to show us the relevant code. If you hadn't ignore the prompt to take the site tour then you'd have a better idea of how to write a good question. ALWAYS show us the relevant code and point exactly where and how its behaviour differs from your expectations. Also, don't just take a screenshot of your entire screen. Only about 25-30% of that image is relevant so why is the re4st of it there, making it harder for us to focus on what is relevant? Windows 10 includes two tools to take screenshots so there's no excuse for not posting only what is relevant.

Comment: My apologies for not following the correct procedure to post in the forum and the image. I am not an experienced programmer and was only looking for help. I have some idea on what Jimi is saying and thank you for your message. My Code is very basic and will update it on the site. Thanks

Comment: I only have a code for the List View and don't know how to program the Tree View to correspond with the removal of a List View Item